Need Help in reading this seal

Can someone tell me what name is written on this seal?
The image is a flipped view

I got: 經邦之志，X在XX. Good luck!

Thank you so much.


Look like 眾 or 爭?
Ref: http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a14193b88782c19374d.html
I don't think it's 經 :
Ref: http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a17266b79526c37034d.html

It's 邦
Reference the 小篆 of : http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a2186b20684c80672d.html

it doesn't like 之 ?
Ref: http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a1749b92254c60287d.html
It's much more like to be 止 ?
Ref: http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a14205b41574c99299d.html

It might be 步
http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a14208b97662c97105d.html
志: http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a13633b68013c87044d.html

帝?  http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a5269b95745c37202d.html

在? http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a9436b68845c55411d.html

韶? http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a21174b16039c73643d.html

練? http://xh.5156edu.com/hzyb/a17353b66302c22875d.html


#7 & #8 should be one of : http://xh.5156edu.com/html/630.html
